# How can I import/use a class diagramm from Enterprise Architect in my Xtext DSL?

Tags: uml, xtext, xmi, ecore

We model our Domain Model as UML class diagram in Enterprise Architect. And we want to design our DSL using Xtext. The DSL should access the domain classes.

I am able to export the Domain Model from Enterprise Architect as XMI file. I am able to reference other DSLs in my actual DSL (like described in http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/xtext-referencing-elements-of-one-dsl-from-another-dsl/).

Is there a way to use my class model in my DSL (without writing a UML DSL)? Maybe via Ecore/Ecorediag/Genmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have an eclipse uml 2 based xmi file the following might work. http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/xtext-2-0-and-uml/

unfortunately Enterprise Architect does not produce such a xmi but there are (commercial) tool s that do that. searching for "enterprise architect eclipse uml" will give you such tools.